# What is the meaning of the question mark in javascript - but it is not a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JS and I can't figure out what this question mark means in this line:
`.querySelector('button')?.removeEventListener ..`

I know what a ternary operator is, but this doesn't look like it.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: See [How the Question Mark (?) Operator Works in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-the-question-mark-works-in-javascript/).

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the Short-circuit evaluation and it's a feature of TypeScript. Not JavaScript .

When whatever before ? Is null or undefined, whatever after ?. Won't be called.
That's to avoid errors like: `undefined has no property removeEventListener`

Edit

I was wrong when I said it's not a feature of JavaScript.  It's actually a new feature. Some browsers that are not updated to the latest don't support it yet (like mine)

Answer (score 1):

Optional chaining (?.)
The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Thanks man! That link helped me. When I googled at myself, I was constantly kicked out by a ternary operator. Thanks!